# Stm32f407 debugging issue

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, keil, flashing, cubemx

I have project of my own that employ stm32f407 mcu. I am using the discovery kit on board st-link to flash my project. Furthermore, I use the cubemx tool to configure the HAL of the project.

The problem is that while generating the HAL layer I checked power optimization check box which by default configure un-configured pins to analog input and I was not configuring the swdio and swclk pins.

I was able to flash one and I can not connect to the project board again. I tried to use the NRST and configuring the stlink to connect under reset with no luck. The NRST pin does not do anything when connected to GND??!!!!

Any idea how to erase the flashed SW to gain ability to flash again?

Answer (score 0):

Place the microcontroller into system bootloader mode by resetting it while the BOOT0 pin is pulled high. While in bootloader mode, the SWD pins will be enabled.

Comment: What if I dont have jumper on the PCB to do that, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the reset button or of you do not have it use a wire.